# How do I share settings between web.config and class library during unit testing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, configuration, web-config

I want to do unit tests in class library, where I need the same config settings as in my main asp.net project's web.config. Therefore I need to duplicate a number of web.config settings to my class library.

I have added settings through the class library's project properties Settings tab.

Then a app.config file is automatically added to the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="ExternalServices.CPR.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <ExternalServices.CPR.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="CprProdHostName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>direkte.cpr.dk</value>
            </setting>
```

Question 1. What is the "best practice" way to share/duplicate some settings from the main web.config to a class library that needs to run unit tests separately but with the same config?

Question 2. I want to read the settings by name. 
I try to read with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CprProdHostName"]; (using System.Configuration;) but it doesn't work, just returns null?

Question 3. What is the purpose of the app.config-file? Because there is no Build action set and the file is not copied to output, it is never visible anywhere by default. This implies I can not change these settings in run time. That's quite strange, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are talking about web config setting like below:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="HostName" value="www.hostname.com" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

please check above part and then use below code to retrieve the key value of HostName

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"]
```

It also requires `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: No, I wasn't talking about web.config. I was talking about the standard project properties - created on the "Settings" tab... Web config is also of interest for me to reach, but since they are in another project, a web project, I decided to duplicate the settings into this project's "Settings", as I discussed above.